# In Clojure, second argument in map-indexed

Tags: clojure

***SPOILER ALERT: This is about answers to [4Clojure question 157](http://www.4clojure.com/problem/157), indexing sequences.***

The fast version of this question: in `(map-indexed #(vector %2 %1) [:a :b :c])`, what is `%2`?

> **Indexing Sequences #157**
>
> Transform a sequence into a sequence of pairs containing the original elements along with their index.
>
> ```
> (= (__ [:a :b :c]) [[:a 0] [:b 1] [:c 2]])
> (= (__ [0 1 3]) '((0 0) (1 1) (3 2)))
> (= (__ [[:foo] {:bar :baz}]) [[[:foo] 0] [{:bar :baz} 1]])
> ```

I pretty quickly managed an answer: `#(map reverse (map-indexed vector %))`, but saw seemingly better answers such as:

`map-indexed #(vector %2 %1)`

by user *tomdmitriev*.

**The question: where does the second argument come from?**

So, for `(map-indexed #(vector %2 %1) [:a :b :c])`, what is `%2`?

The [docs for map-indexed](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/map-indexed) state:

> Returns a lazy sequence consisting of the result of applying f to 0
> and the first item of coll, followed by applying f to 1 and the second
> item in coll, etc, until coll is exhausted. Thus **function f should
> accept 2 arguments, index and item.** Returns a stateful transducer when
> no collection is provided. -- *my emphasis*

Well, I also only provided one argument, the collection from the 4Clojure question. I'm not sure how this is working... is there some kind of an implied or implicit argument?

Thanks for any help clearing this up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function passed to [map-indexed](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/map-indexed) is a function of [index item]. Easy to understand with:

```
 (map-indexed (fn [idx itm] [idx itm]) "item")
 ; ([0 "item"])
```

It is actually a *apply_map_with_index*

So back to your example, with:

```
 (map-indexed #(vector %2 %1) [:a :b :c])
 ; ([:a 0] [:b 1] [:c 2])
```

Will create a small sequence of vector, made from %2 the item, %1  the index.

You can also compare the above with the easy to understand:

```
 (map-indexed #(vector %1 %2) [:a :b :c])
 ; ([0 :a] [1 :b] [2 :c])
```

which creates a sequence of small vector of [index item].

EDIT:

If we decompose this in two steps, it gives:

```
  ; we need to define a function 
  ; with two parameters 
  (defn my-function [index item]
      (vector item index))

  ; map-indexed uses a function with 
  ; two parameters
  (map-indexed 
       my-function 
       [:a :b :c])
```

Comment: Thanks, maybe I get it. So, to put it prosaically, we provide the function with its second argument (the collection), and `map-indexed` itself provides the first (the index)?

Comment: no. map-indexed needs a two parameters function as first parameter, and a collection as second parameter. map-indexed then 'loops' on each item of the collection.

Comment: Ah, now I see.  Your comment here and the edit in your answer cleared it up very nicely, thanks.